# How to make UIScrollView scroll gesture "sub-servient"

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am using the word "subservient" as I don't know the correct term. I have tried various things to make the my UIScrollView the last gesture to be checked, so that gestures that belong to subviews of the scroll view will fire before or instead of the scrollview.

For example I have a scroll view that contains a subview, which has a pan gesture recognizer. When I try to pan, sometimes the scroll view's pan fires, sometime the sub view's pan gesture fires. I want the subview's gesture to fire consistently instead of the scroll view if that view is directly dragged.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the "delaysContentTouches" property of scrollview to true?

Or you can subclass UIScrollVeiw and override the touchesShouldCancelInContentView: method like this:

```
-(BOOL)touchesShouldCancelInContentView:(UIView *)view
{

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {//or whatever class you want to override
        return YES;
    }

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]]) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: if that doesn't work, you will have to subclass the scrollview and the view you are using and intercept touch events from scrollview and send them to that view